# Why won't Visual Studio step into 3rd party code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I've reviewed the threads I can find on this subject, but none of the proposed solutions seem to help.  So I'll ask again!

My Visual Studio 2015 will not step into 3rd party code for which I have the pdb in my bin folder when I run in debug mode.  I even see the pdb file downloaded as Visual Studio loads symbols.  When I attempt to step into the 3rd party code, Visual Studio complains that it can't find the .cs file.  I've tried toggling the 'Enable Just My Code' setting.  Visual Studio *used* to be able to step into 3rd party code; I'm not sure what changed.

I am attempting to step in the context of a unit test, in case that matters.  The pdb file is in my unit test bin directory.

My debug settings are below.  What am I missing?

[image: General debug settings]

[image]

**Edit: Context menu from right-click on method in call stack**

[image]

Comment: Open Debug | Modules while debugging and see if your symbol for the third party component is loaded or not.

Comment: Handy tool - I didn't know about this option.  But it looks like it's there.  Symbol status for the pdb of interest is listed as 'Symbols loaded'.

Comment: Please just try to right-click on a function that you want to load the pdb for, then go to 'Load Symbols'. Browse for the correct pdb, and press OK. After that, it should be able to provide information for the calls in that pdb.

Comment: @FletchZhou-MSFT, I right-clicked on a few methods in the base class in the referenced DLL but there does not seem to be a 'Load Symbols' menu item.  Any ideas why?

Comment: @ket Oh, sorry, it's through Call Stack window while debugging with a break

Comment: For some reason, I don't get the 'Load Symbols' option even when I right-click on the method of interest from the call stack - see my edit above.  I _do_ get the option if I right-click on one of the grayed-out methods.

Comment: Another thing I've noticed is that when I use the 'Go To Declaration' option on one of these methods, I don't get the actual code, but a decompilation from the Jetbrains decompiler.  If I choose to use Visual Studio's navigation option, I get a message saying 'The symbol has no implementations'.

Comment: It seems to me that the symbol is loaded, but for some reason Visual Studio insists on looking for the .cs file, which it can't find.

Comment: @ket Which .cs file is it looking for? It seems you are debugging the unit test method, have you add the project under test to unit test project's reference? Could the unit test method run well?

Comment: The unit test runs and passes.  The debugger is looking for MefCompositionService.cs, which is defined in the 3rd-party DLL.  That DLL is referenced via Nuget, in a project.json file.

Comment: @ket I've edited my answer, please have a look, as the source code which is necessary to debug the source.

Comment: I do have the source files on my machine, but I have to manually locate them now.  Previously VS would find them directly without any need from me to specify where they are.  Any idea why this behavior changed, and what I can do to get it back?

Comment: @ketThe debugger searches for source files in these four location based the official doc:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_1 
May I ask how you specified the location in your case? 
But it seems that you could successfully locate them now, I assume you’ve already resolved the original question at this post?  If so for the new question, you may open another thread for about Visual Studio issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have **source code** to source debug.

Pdb file only contains debug information which is like mapping between executable code and your source code. With pdb VS debugger knows where in source files each instruction is located, but it still **needs to have source files** to show you the code.

When it cannot find source file VS debugger will show dialog box to browse for the source file. So without source code, VS cannot debug it properly.

Workaround is to use some tools like **Resharper**, **Reflector** which could decompile it